# Database(es)/tools choice for many parallel bulk inserts

Tags: database

There will be REST API that will collect data from mobile devices. Each mobile device will cache data (to some limit) before sending them to API. So for example every 4 minutes each mobile device will send 50 data rows to API. One row looks like this:

```
{"uid": "123", "lon": "12.1", "lat": "12.1", "vel": "145", "timestamp": "12345"}
```

So for example when there will be 1000 active devices then it might happen (worst case) that there will be 1000 parallel writes and each write will insert 50 "rows". So in fact in one moment API will try to insert 50k rows to database. Moreover if each of device will send data 2 hours a day then each day there will be 1 500 000 (1.5 milion) new rows.

Later on, all collected data will be sent to another service, in bigger chunks (by some kind of worker that will wait for X rows to appear in DB and he will send them to the external service). All rows which will be older than 7 days might be deleted. Also one of API endpoints will allow to retrieve data for one of last 7 days based on "uid" (user_id) and "timestamp" fields.

The question is which database to use (or combination of databases/tools) to handle to many writes/sec?

My first idea was to use DynamoDB as it's super easy scalable (I can just buy writes/sec) but it's impossible for it to handle 50k writes in one moment. So my second idea was to use some intermediate database(es) to cache chunks of 50 rows that will be inserted to primary db by a background worker/process with some limit of processed chunks in same moment.

I believe todays there are many apps that gather lot of data from mobile devices (like GPS position, velocity, etc) - how do they do it?

I am not asking on dba because it might be not only database-specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I just inserted 1.5 million rows into a fully indexed table. I used a single thread, PostgreSQL database, ran on my notebook. The whole thing took 45.1 seconds.

If this is all your daily data, do not even bother inventing a wheel. Just get yourself PostgreSQL and a multicore server.